# Switching cold cathode fluorescent lights on and off without relay?

Tags: mosfet, switches, inverter, 12v, ccfl

I have a few sets of 2-in-1 CCFLs that are designed to be powered off the 12V rail of a computer PSU. I'm planning to build a large 7-seg display using them so I'd like to be able to switch them on and off independently using an Arduino and ideally a MOSFET. The problem is that two CCFL's share the same inverter so I can only wire a MOSFET in after the voltage has been upped.

I tried to measure the voltage coming from the inverter to no avail, I'm not sure if the supply even gets converted from DC to AC? The tubes draw around 500mA each.

I have experience with Arduino but am not well versed in electrical engineering, so my question to anyone that would answer is what would be the best way to switch these off independently?

Should I buy extra inverters and switch at the 12V or is there a way I can use the existing inverters and switch after the inversion? The cheaper, the better!

Comment: No schematic, it's hard to say. Is the inverter actually two inverters in a box (I have some like this), or is it a single inverter, with the CCFLs in parallel?

Comment: @Passerby it is a single with two CCFLs in parallel - I opened it up and then managed to blow the fuse in one of them whilst measuring, oops!